# MS Exchange 2007 access via ASP.NET Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, exchange-server, ews-managed-api

How do I reference a MS Exchange Server 2007 API via a ASP.NET Web Service ?

Hint : MS Exchange API's are exposed as a Web Service.

The code behind for the existing code for the ASP.NET web service is written in C#.

What is the best way to pass an exception/error back to the consumer of this web service?

Hint : Assuming an error occurred is a message text and an error code.

Comment: are those hints for *our* benefit, or your benefit while finding the solution to your homework?

Comment: thats for the viewers benefit. I was wondering if you have a solution. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Web service can access MS Exchange Server 2007 by Exchange Web Service API or via Exchange Web Service Managed API.

Comment: This doesn't answer the hard part of the question (best way to pass back an exception)